# Emailing admin when a 500 error occurs

Tags: python, bottle

How can I send an email to admin when a 500 error occurs, in python.

The web framework I'm using is 'bottle'.

Comment: from the title I initially thought you wanted to send 500 emails all at once to that poor admin! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `@error(code)` decorator to define an error handling page, like so:

```
from bottle import run, error, route

@error(500)
def handle_500_error(code):
  # add mail send code here
  return "Error message here"

@route("/test_500")
def cause_error():
  raise Exception

run()
```

Just navigate to `/test_500` to see it in action

You can of course use a template for the error page just like with any other page. I'm not sure if there's a way to get the built-in bottle error page while having an error handler.

Edit:

Apparently if you're using the latest Bottle v0.8, the function to which you apply the `@error` decorator receives as a parameter not the error code, but an [`bottle.HTTPError`](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.HTTPError) object, which contains the exception and traceback.

Alternatively, you can set Bottle to not handle exceptions by setting `bottle.app().catchall` to `False` as described [here](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-errors-and-redirects), and then use some appropriate WSGI middleware to handle them and send the email (e.g. something like [this](http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/modules/pylons/middleware.html#module-weberror.errormiddleware)).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want to know that is there any thing provided by bottle, which we can use to send 500 errors email as provided in django. (In case if I don't want to write the above code)

Comment: Actually your suggestion can only email me. I could not get where it went wrong because it will not give any traceback as django gives. So, is there any alternate way?

Comment: I think there must be some way to get the exception. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a line from the [Bottle documentation](http://bottle.paws.de/page/docs).

> All unhandled exceptions other than `bottle.HTTPError` will result in a 500 Internal Server Error response, so they won't crash your WSGI server.

Judging by this you would want to catch those `Exception`s and write the code to send an email to whomsoever it may concern. Your code will go into the `try` block and you will have a some code for the `bottle.HTTPError` exception and then code to catch all other `Exception`s which sends the desired email.