# E-mail traceback on errors in Bottle framework

Tags: python, error-handling, bottle

I am using the Bottle framework. I have set the `@error` decorator so I am able to display my customized error page, and i can also send email if any 500 error occurs, but I need the complete traceback to be sent in the email. Does anyone know how to have the framework include that in the e-mail?

Answer (score 3):

in the error500 function written after the @error decorator to serve my customized error page, wrote `error.exception` and `error.traceback`, these two give the exception and complete traceback of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging mode enables full tracebacks:

```
from bottle import debug
debug(True)
```

From there, you will need to pipe `stderr` to a file, then send it.

Comment: The accepted answer here is much better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324743/emailing-admin-when-a-500-error-occurs

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the reply, i have done the debug(True), i am able to get the 500 error with traceback on my browser, how can i pipe the stderr to a file, can you show some example.

Comment: Hey tim, thanks for the help, i got the solution, in the error500 function written after the @error decorator to serve my customized error page, wrote error.exception and error.traceback, these two give  you the exception and complete traceback of the error message, i took help from Marcel the creator of Bottle Framework and he showed me the solution.